# Continued text search in an excel column

Tags: database, vba, search, text, find

I am using below code to find a phrase "Phase End" in an excel column where the data exists from 1 to 9 phases. Problem is I can find phase 1 to 9 by its " Phase 1" "Phase 2" ...  But all phases have the same ending phrases like "Phase End".  When I do the search, is it possible to skip the identified phases and continue the search only in the remaining part of the excel column? For example, after identifying "Phase 3" and its "Phase End"   I want to continue the search through the values below phase 3 but not before them.

```
Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("B36") = Cells.Find(What:="Phase 1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1).Value
Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("C36") = Cells.Find(What:="End Phase", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1).Value

Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("B37") = Cells.Find(What:="phase 2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1).Value
Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("C37") = Cells.Find(What:="end phase", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1).Value

Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("B38") = Cells.Find(What:="phase 3", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1).Value
Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("C38") = Cells.Find(What:="end phase", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1).Value
```

Comment: Essentially, I am looking for a better search of cells   to identify phase 1 and its phase end at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question but maybe this will help you out:

```
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim EndRng As Range
Dim StartRng As Range
Dim SearchStr As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim NewStartRow As Integer

StartRow = 35
SearchStr = "End Phase"

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To 9

    NewStartRow = StartRow + i

    'Set your own search range here
    Set StartRng = Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("B1:B100").Find(What:="Phase " & i)
    Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("B" & NewStartRow).Value = Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Cells(StartRng.Row, StartRng.Column - 1).Value

    'Finds the first End Phase and renames it (also edit the range here)
    Set EndRng = Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range("C1:C100").Find(What:=SearchStr)
    Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").Range(EndRng.Address).Value = "End Phase" & i

'Do whatever you want next

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks BjornBogers, that worked perfectly. Appreciate your efforts to find solution even when my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Sub main24()
    Dim iPhase As Long
    Dim afterCell As Range

    With Workbooks(OpenWB).Worksheets("Home").UsedRange
        Set afterCell = .Cells(.Count) '<--| set it to the last lookedup range for the first iteration so as to have 'Find()' start from the first one
        For iPhase = 1 To 9 '<--| iterate through phases
            Set afterCell = .Find(What:="Phase " & iPhase, After:=afterCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False) '<--| set 'afterCell' to the found current "Phase" one
            .Parent.Range("B36").Offset(iPhase - 1) = afterCell.Offset(0, -1).Value '<--| update corresponding output cell with adjacent value to the left
            Set afterCell = .Find(What:="End Phase", After:=afterCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False) '<--| set 'afterCell' to the found current "End Phase" one
            .Parent.Range("C36").Offset(iPhase - 1) = afterCell.Offset(, -1).Value '<--| update corresponding output cell with adjacent value to the left
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello.. Great idea. Thanks for this, now I can write a better code with your help